# Amcharts: category data is not shown while changing the cursor

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amstock

In an Amstock examples ([1](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/9b67840efd3decb2e04106faf5991f6b),[2](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/stock-comparing-external-data/)) I saw that the category field block is enabled during moving a cursor.

However I didn't manage to replicate this logic in my [project](https://codesandbox.io/s/9jz98r2x3o)

My `chartCursorSettings` are following

```
   this.chart = window.AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
      "path": AmCharts_path,
      "type": "stock",
      "theme": "light",

      "dataSets": portfolioData.map(function (port, idx) {
        return {
          "title": port.name,
          "fieldMappings": [{
            "fromField": "value",
            "toField": "value"
          }],
          "dataProvider": port.data,
          "compared": (idx === 0 ? false : true),
          "categoryField": "date"
        }
      }),

      "panels": [{
        "showCategoryAxis": false,
        "title": "Value",
        "percentHeight": 70,
        "stockGraphs": [
          {
            "id": "g1",
            "valueField": "value",
            "comparable": true,
            "compareField": "value",
            "balloonFunction": this.ballonRender,
            "compareGraphBalloonFunction": this.ballonRender
          }]
      }],

      "chartScrollbarSettings": {
        "graph": "g1"
      },

      "categoryAxis": {
        "parseDates": true
      },

      "balloon": {
          "fixedPosition": true,
          "maxWidth": 10000
      },

      "chartCursorSettings": {
        "valueBalloonsEnabled": true,
        "categoryBalloonEnabled": true,
        "categoryBalloonAlpha": 0.2,
        "bulletsEnabled": true,
        "bulletSize": 10,
        "categoryBalloonDateFormats": [
            {period:'fff',format:'JJ:NN:SS'},
            {period:'ss',format:'JJ:NN:SS'},
            {period:'mm',format:'JJ:NN'},
            {period:'hh',format:'JJ:NN'},
            {period:'DD',format:'MMM DD'},
            {period:'WW',format:'MMM DD'},
            {period:'MM',format:'MMM'},
            {period:'YYYY',format:'YYYY'}
          ]
      },

      "listeners": [{
        "event": "zoomed",
        "method": this.calulateMetrics
      }],

      "periodSelector": {
        "position": "bottom",
        "periods": [{
          "period": "MM",
          "count": 1,
          "label": "1 month"
        }, {
          "period": "MM",
          "count": 3,
          "label": "3 month"
        }, {
          "period": "MM",
          "count": 6,
          "label": "6 month"
        }, {
          "period": "YYYY",
          "count": 1,
          "label": "1 year"
        }, {
          "period": "YTD",
          "label": "YTD"
        }, {
          "period": "MAX",
          "selected": true,
          "label": "All"
        }]
      },
    });
  },
```

Also I set `parseDates` to `true`

```
"categoryAxis": {
  "parseDates": true
},
```

I tried to specify the `"dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD"` but it didn't help me either.

How can I enable this field?
[image]

I pass the JavaScript `Date` object to category field.

Comment: I don't see any AmCharts code inside your sandbox link. Can you actually post your full makeChart code or modify your sandbox code so that we actually see your chart? The settings in your question should work as long as it is set in the top-level of the chart object and is set as part of the `chartCursorSettings` object, *not* categoryCursorSettings.

Comment: @xorspark hm, from my side it works fine. Anyway the AmChart component (`amcandlestick.vue`) is in `src->components->widgets. Can you check whether this files exist, please?

Comment: @xorspark also I updated the code

Answer (score 2):

The categoryBalloon from the chartCursor requires that the `categoryAxis` be visible. Setting `showCategoryAxis: false` in your panel effectively removes the balloon since you're removing the category axis.

If you don't want the categoryAxis labels but want the category balloon, set `labelsEnabled` to `false` in your `categoryAxesSettings`.

```
AmCharts.makeChart("...", {
  // ...
  panels: [{
    //showCategoryAxis: false, //comment/remove this
    // ...
  }],
  // ...
  categoryAxesSettings: {
    labelsEnabled: false //if you want to remove the axis labels but keep the balloon
  },
  // ...
});
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/19ea338b007b9a0d2480d0f2176f2e84?editors=0010)

Some helpful clarifications:

- `categoryAxis` doesn't do anything at the top level of the stock chart and all stock charts has `parseDates` enabled by default. `categoryAxesSettings` is the equivalent in this case.
- [`dateDateFormat`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/AmStockChart#dataDateFormat) tells AmCharts how to parse your string-based dates in your `dataProvider`. Since you're using `Date` objects, this doesn't do anything.